# Installing Windows 2000 from a USB drive on semi-modern hardware

Tags: windows-2000

I have an HP computer that currently has Windows XP on the hard drive, and I was thinking whether I could install Windows 2000 on the computer.  I assumed it might work because Windows 2000 uses the NT kernel and it has a bigger chance of running.

I used the Rufus software to create a bootable USB drive with the Windows 2000 ISO image.  At first the setup program appears to start fine, but when I try to begin installation, it gives me this error message:

> Setup cannot find the End User Licensing Agreement (EULA)

This error appears right after the initial screen offering the choices to begin setup, repair, or quit.

Although I could burn the ISO onto a CD/DVD, I would rather not.

If it's possible to install Windows 2000 from a USB drive then please tell me how; if not, it's OK, I don't mind.

Comment: Windows 2000 almost certainly can't install from USB sticks. Setup surely lacks the drivers. It was a pain in the rear making sure you had the right disk drivers ('press F6 now').

Comment: At what point do you get the 'no EULA' error?  Before or after the base OS files are copied to the fixed disk?

Comment: What does the installer say *before* giving you “the options to continue setup, repair, and quit”?

Comment: Is your question _specifically about_ installing Windows 2000 without using a CD or DVD? Or is it about why you're getting the error you're getting? (Both would probably help you install it, but it depends which thing you're most curious about. "Help me install this software" isn't really a Stack Exchangey question; that's more a tech support thing.)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I want to install it with a USB (hoping i don't need cd/dvd) and im getting that error so yeah, Both.

Comment: I meant, if you could boot into pure DOS, and access the installation files, you should be able to launch `\I386\WINNT.EXE` from the DOS session to start installation. I remember Windows NT 3.x could be installed in this manner.

Comment: @user3840170 That sounds like a separate question; perhaps you could [ask it](/questions/ask)? (I would be interested in learning the answer.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142076/discussion-on-question-by-humancoder1123-installing-windows-2000-from-a-usb-driv).

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Is it, though? After the question was edited, I think this strategy might as well be written as an answer here.

Comment: And speaking of editing, though I initially cast a vote to close, I think in the edited form (focusing on installation from USB specifically) it’s now focused enough to be answerable.

Comment: Note that "USB drive" and "CD/DVD drive" are not mutually exclusive (although the setup program likely won't know how to read from a USB-connected external CD/DVD drive, that may be helped by the modern firmware)

Comment: @BenVoigt the PC has a disk drive, But no worries, i was able to install with winsetupfromusb.